# is it possible to get page reviews and reviewer's name and profile photo url with restFB library?

Tags: spring, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I have found restFB client library in spring for facebook graph api , i have to get page reviews and reviwers name and profile photo. I am searching for this in https://restfb.com/javadoc-3/com/restfb/types/Page.html , but couldn't find any method for this

is it possible to get page reviews and reviewer's name and profile photo url with restFB library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the ratings is a bit more tricky.

Let's assume you have a `FacebookClient` with the correct page access token. Then you can start a call like this:

```
Connection<OpenGraphRating> ogRatingConn = 
      facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/ratings", 
           OpenGraphRating.class, 
           Parameter.with("fields", "reviewer,review_text,has_rating,recommendation_type"));
```

Then you can iterate over the connection. Check the `OpenGraphRating` object for the methods you can use.

I suggest additionally to check the `open_graph_story` field, because with this you can get some more information. Then the request looks like this (for the ease of use I removed the other `OpenGraphRating` fields here).

```
Connection<OpenGraphRating> ogRatingConn = 
      facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/ratings", 
           OpenGraphRating.class, 
           Parameter.with("fields", "open_graph_story{id,from,message,publish_time,type,data{recommendation_type,rating,language,review_text},comments.limit(0).summary(1).filter(stream)}"));
```

In this example you can access the fields with the `getOpenGraphStory` method that is part of the `OpenGraphRating` object.

Comment: Sir, thanks a lot for answer, it was very useful for me. I have modified query a little bit in this form :  `Parameter.with("fields", "reviewer{id,name,picture},review_text,created_time,recommendation_type"))` , before profile_url returns null , but now everything is okay. I have one more question : can this library be used instead of `spring-security-oauth2-client` ?  now I use oauth for authentication , restFB for http requests.Can I control everything in restFB library?

Comment: RestFB does not provide a full-featured oauth2 client, but you can built the authentication workflow with RestFB, too. The FacebookClient class provides some methods for this, you can built the scope list with the ScopeBuilder, but you need to write some servlets (or whatever you use in your framework) as authentication entrypoint for the user. But this should not a big thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use facebook official api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/{page-id}/ratings',
    '{access-token}'
  );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
/* handle the result */
```